# Lombok with JsonDeserializer

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization, lombok

I have a JSON string that I want to deserialize into a class. The JSON looks like so:

```json
{ "data": { "name": "Box 1", "size": "10x20" } }
```

I can deserialize this into the following class:

```java
@Builder
@Value
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Box1.Box1Builder.class)
public class Box1 {

    @JsonProperty("data")
    Box1Data data;

    public static Box1 of(String json) throws IOException {
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Box1.class);
    }

    @Builder
    @Value
    @JsonDeserialize(builder = Box1Data.Box1DataBuilder.class)
    static class Box1Data {

        @JsonProperty("name")
        String name;

        @JsonProperty("size")
        String size;

    }

}
```

The above class looks clumsy since it has a useless hierarchy of `data`. I can get rid of it like so:

```java
@Builder
@Value
@JsonDeserialize(using = Box2Deserializer.class)
public class Box2 {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;

    @JsonProperty("size")
    String size;

    public static Box2 of(String json) throws IOException {
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Box2.class);
    }

    static class Box2Deserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Box2> {

        @Override
        public Box2 deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            var node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
            var dataNode = node.get("data");
            return Box2.builder()
                    .name(dataNode.get("name").toString())
                    .size(dataNode.get("size").toString())
                    .build();
        }
    }

}
```

But here, I hit a dead-end. I want the `size` field to be parsed into a `Dimension` instance. I can write a custom deserializer for `size` that parses a `String` and returns a proper `Dimension`, but I cannot use it via field annotations (`@JsonDeserialize(using = SizeDeserializer.class)` since the presence of `JsonDeserialize` class annotation forces it to be ignored in the case for `Box1`, and in the case for `Box2`, it's ignored cuz I'm building the box manually.

Is there an elegant solution to all this mess? What I want is to read the given JSON into a class like this:

```java
@Builder
@Value
public class Box3 {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;

    @JsonProperty("size")
    Dimension size;

    public static Box3 of(String json) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Asim

Comment: is there some reason why you are manually deserializing Box2 instead of taking advantage of data binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add to @Iprakashv solution, besides only the needs for the `JsonRootName` type annotation and mapper serialization / deserialization for root node wrapping, you only need a custom type converter from a raw type to your custom type:

```
@Builder
@Value
@JsonRootName("data")
public class Box {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;

    @JsonDeserialize(converter = StringToDimensionConverter.class)
    @JsonProperty("size")
    Dimension size;

    public static Box of(String json) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        return mapper.readValue(json, Box.class);
    }

    private static class StringToDimensionConverter extends StdConverter<String, Dimension> {
        @Override
        public DataWrapper.Box1Data.Dimension convert(String s) {
            return new DataWrapper.Box1Data.Dimension(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually do not need a custom deserializer and the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation. The `ObjectMapper` provides a configuration to enable wrapping/unwrapping a root value which can be provided using the `@JsonRootName` annotation over the Wrapper object class.

```java
@Builder
@Value
@JsonRootName("data")
public class Box {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;

    @JsonProperty("size")
    String size;

    public static Box of(String json) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        return mapper.readValue(json, Box.class);
    }
}
```

PS: Totally missed the `Dimension` part in the question, for that, you can use a custom deserializer as mentioned in other answer.

Comment: Thank you for this! Annotations, it seems, are quite powerful after all. :)